# проблемы с выводом REST

Tags: c#, rest

Имеется 2 таблицы:

*Встреча* (id, тема, idPlace).

*Место* (id, адрес). Связаны по полю `idPlace`->`id`.

Созданы модели для этих таблиц:

```cs
public class Place  
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Address { get; set; }  
}
```

```cs
public class Meeting  
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Theme { get; set; }  
    public Place FPlace { get; set; }  
}
```

Репозиторий:

```cs
public Meeting GetMeeting(int id)  
    {  
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))  
        {  
            connection.Open();  
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())  
            {  
                command.CommandText = "SELECT m.id, m.theme,     
                                       p.address " +  
                                      "FROM [dbo].meeting AS m " +  
                                      "INNER JOIN [dbo].place AS p " +  
                                      "ON m.place_id = p.id " +  
                                      "WHERE m.id = @id";  

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        return new Meeting
                        {
                            Id = (int)reader["id"],
                            Theme = (string)reader["theme"],
                            Time = (DateTime)reader["time"],
                            Duration = (TimeSpan)reader["duration"],
                            FPlace = new Place
                            {
                                Address = (string)reader["address"]
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и сам Rest:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/meeting/get/{id}")]
public Meeting GetMeeting(int id)
{
    return _repository.GetMeeting(id);
}
```

На мой взгляд, проблема кроется здесь

```cs
FPlace = new Place  
{  
     Address = (string)reader["address"]  
}
```

При GET-запросе (`api/meeting/get/{id}`) выдает не только данные из таблицы *Встреча*, адрес из таблицы *Place*, а еще и `Id = 0`(из таблицы *Place*).

Как бы от него избавиться (Id)?

Comment: а в каком формате результат отдаете? вы хотите всегда не отдавать `Id` из объекта _Place_?

Comment: Я не хочу его получать, мне нужен только `Adress` из таблицы *Place*. Из-за того, что я создаю новый экземпляр класса Fplace, он мне еще кидает `id` (Это как я понимаю, может не в этом проблема).

Comment: Именно в этом, так как не указаны никакие параметры сериализации, сериализуются все поля, не важно есть там значения или нет

Comment: вы не ответили _в каком формате результат отдаете?_ xml? json? еще что-то?

Comment: Да, извините. JSON

Comment: можете поставить для этого поля атрибут: _[JsonIgnore]_, но в таком случае он всегда будет игнорироваться

Comment: вообще, это практически то же самое - я спросил просто потому, что разные атрибуты могут использоваться

Comment: еще один вариант описан в [Reducing Serialized JSON Size](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) - можно создавать свой ресолвер, в котором например проверять - если указанное свойство имеет какое-то определенное значение - не добавлять его в результат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32734/discussion-between-grundy-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант **А**: как уже было сказано в комментариях

```
public class Place  
{  
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Address { get; set; }  
}
```

Вариант **B**:

```
var meet = _repository.GetMeeting(id);
return new { id = meet.Id, theme = a.Theme, place = meet.FPlace.Address};
```

получается плоский список без излишеств
конечно неплохо было бы убедиться,  что `meet` у нас не `null`

Comment: В Варианте `B` преобразование анонимного типа в *Meeting* невозможно

Comment: @romka.pm, можно в объявлении метода _Meeting_ на _object_ заменить

Comment: Все равно он мне `id=0` присылает.

Comment: WebAPI умеет работать и возвращать значения в виде JSON и XML, это зависит от того, что клиент понимает. А принимает он данные в формате JSON. Не знаю почему, но сейчас у меня Crome не понимает, что ему приходит. Fiddler принимает Json, все ок.

Comment: @Dmitry,  при `Get-запросе` получаю JSON, который содержит поля `Meeting.Id = значение`, `Meeting.Theme = значение`,  и т.д., а также `FPlace.Address = значение` и `FPlace.Id = 0(всегда)`. Мне это поле из Json-a вообще убрать хочется. Дело в том, что если использовать способ `B`, тогда браузер перестает понимать формат (от принимает XML).

Comment: @Dmitry, если я добавлю сколь угодно много полей в класс *Place*, то они буду либо `null`, либо `0`, в зависимости от того - это тип значения или ссылочный тип. Проблема. в конструкторе (я указал в самом начале, где кроется проблема), т.к. я не присваиваиваю им (полям) никакого значения за ненадобнастью.

Comment: @romka.pm, а атрибут-то ставили? самый первый вариант?

Comment: @romka.pm, тут вообще скорее - указали разную версию

Comment: @Dmitry `[IgnoreDataMember]` отлично.  Поправь ответ, убери  `[XmlIgnore]`, `[JsonIgnore]`. С атрибутом `[IgnoreDataMember]` и xml и json отображается корректно (как и хотелось без `id=0`).